# Eliminating duplicate code in type switch

Tags: go, struct, casting, dry

Since I can't use fallthrough in type switch, is there any way to merge the two cases in this code?

```
switch v := moduleSource.(type) {
            case Driver:
               dec.Decode(&v)
                _, _ = ormInstance.Insert(&v)

            case Metric:
                dec.Decode(&v)
                _, _ = ormInstance.Insert(&v)

            default:
                    fmt.Println("unknown type")
    }
```

The ORM call `ormInstance.Insert()` has to have the right struct for it to work.

Comment: just `case Driver, Metric:`

Comment: It compiles but doesn't work - v is unknown if you do that

Answer (score 0):

A list of types are allowed in a type switch, as defined in the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches).

```
switch v := moduleSource.(type) {
    case *Driver, *Metric:
        // v has the same type as moduleSource
        dec.Decode(v)
        _, _ = ormInstance.Insert(v)

    default:
        fmt.Println("unknown type")
}
```

Comment: When I do that v is not being casted (stays ModuleSource)

Comment: @kambi: I have updated my answer to remove taking the address of `v`.

Comment: @kambi: Then you need to make sure that you set `moduleSource` to one.

Comment: Yes it is set, when I use the separated version of Driver and Metric it works well